# MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the following code to open an intent to capture and image and return the result with a specific request_code

```
    Intent imageCapture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File mediaStorageDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"zzz");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("zzz", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    Uri imageFile=Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg"));
    Log.d("zzz",""+imageFile); // to check whether filename is correct or not!!!
    imageCapture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFile);      
    startActivityForResult(imageCapture, 1);
```

This intent shows the camera intent for capturing an image and does everything just as fine. It also captures the image, but just when the save button is clicked, it encounters a runtimeException.

```
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {idiot.houses.numberslider/idiot.houses.numberslider.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at edu.vuum.mocca.ui.story.CreateStoryFragment.onActivityResult(CreateStoryFragment.java:316)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at edu.vuum.mocca.ui.story.StoryActivityBase.onActivityResult(StoryActivityBase.java:291)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5372)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
    03-17 09:34:32.324: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: problem is inside onActivityResult method so post onActivityResult method code with question

Answer (score 0):

I think following code is helpful to you.

```
//code for calling intent
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);  
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

//code write in onActivityResult() method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;
    switch (requestCode) {

    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                   break;
        }
 }
```